# Entity Framework Many-Too-Many Not Populating Results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, ef-fluent-api

I'm trying to map a many-too-many relationship in C# EF with code first migrations.

The issue that I'm having is that no results are being populated from the related table. Take this piece of code for example, `_role` contains no permissions whereas it should contain 4 results:

```
foreach (Role _role in _dbContext.Roles) //_dbContext.Roles.Count = 2
{
    foreach(Permission _permission in _role.Permissions) //_role.Permissions.Count = 0
    {
        //Do something with each _permission
    }
}
```

The classes look like this:

```
[Table("Roles")]
public partial class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        Permissions = new HashSet<Permission>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}

[Table("Permissions")]
public partial class Permission
{
    public Permission()
    {
        Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int PermissionId { get; set; }

    public string PermissionName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

And finally the Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Permission>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Roles)
    .WithMany(e => e.Permissions)
    .Map(m => m
        .ToTable("_Lnk_Role_Permission")
        .MapLeftKey("PermissionId")
        .MapRightKey("RoleId"));
```

After inspecting the database, the tables, keys and data are all in order and manually adding and querying data produces the correct results. When trying to access the data, roles are present but no permissions.

Can anybody see where it could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after hours of head scratching, I missed out `Virtual` from the `ICollection`. The modified class looks like so:

```
public partial class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        Permissions = new HashSet<Permission>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public Virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; } //Notice the virtual?!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the Include statement.

```
foreach (var role in _dbContext.Roles.Include(x => x.Permissions)) 
{
    ...
}
```

The virtual keyword is good practice and plays a role in how the data is loaded.  If you aren't careful, you can end up doing 1+N queries (1 for the Role object + N more for each Permission).  The Include statement tells EF to effectively join the tables in the DB query so that the data is available in memory for handling your nested for loops.

Apologies for linking elsewhere, but MSDN links should be here for a while.  This is a pretty good read to understand the implications of virtual/non-virtual and with/without the Include statement:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to clarify in my own head, so the `Virtual` keyword should be there but I should also use the `Include` statement to load the data? Thanks

Comment: `virtual` says to use lazy loading for the role.Permissions.  In your for loop case, it would result in 1 select being done for each `role` in `Roles` (which would generally be bad for performance).  By using `.Include`, you are effectively telling EF to load `Roles` joined with `Permissions` in a single shot so the body of your loop doesn't require any round-trips to the database.